# Javascript OR Expression: return Operand that is *not* NaN

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

I have an OR expression that should return the operand that is anything else than `NaN`:

```
(1 || NaN) // evaluates to 1 
(NaN || 1) // evaluates to 1
```

But when the other operand is also a falsy value like `0`, `null`, `undefined` or `false`, Javascript returns always the rightmost operand:

```
(0 || NaN) // evaluates to NaN
(NaN || 0) // evaluates to 0
// same for combinations of 0, null, undefined and false
```

Is there a way to fit the desired behaviour "Return the operand that is *not* `NaN`" into a nice & short expression or do I have to rely on an if/else construct?

Comment: why not take (always) `NaN` as first operand?

Comment: @Nina Scholz: The example is simplified, I don't know which operand is `NaN`, each operand is the result of another function/expression

Comment: you can use `ternary`.

Comment: @all: I think all answers were great and it will take some time for me to choose one to accept, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a default [*falsy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value at the end of the expression, like

```
result = yourValue0 || yourValue1 || 0;
```

In this case, you get either a *truthy* value of `yourValueX` or the **last** *falsy* value.

Answer (score 5):

Use an if-else-expression, also known as the conditional operator:

```
!isNaN(a) ? a : b
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var notNaN = [value1, value2, value3].find(item => !Number.isNaN(item))
```

Comment: Might as well use `Array#some`, if you're doing a boolean check

Answer (score 1):

This kind of operators use a lazy mechanism for their computation and this concept is called short circuting in javascript. Basically, JS returns value as soon as it feels no more computation is required to evaluate this expression. So, if its an && operator it will return as soon as it finds first non-truthy(0, "", null, undefined, NaN) as for && operator if any of the operands is non-truthy there is no point check rest of the operands as expression is already non-truthy, so it returns that value and exits, now if all the operands are truthy it checks till last and returns the last value. For || its just the opposite as soon as it finds first truthy value it returns otherwise keeps checking till last and returns it.